# BeautifulSoup and Python getter

Tags: python, recursion, beautifulsoup

I`m a Python noob, only started 3 days ago, so please help me:
I have the following code:

def parseWebContentAndUploadDAO(self,liSet):
        if not liSet:
            print "no element found"
        else:
            print len(liSet)

```
    almaProdList = deque() ;

    for item in liSet:

        loopProd = Alma.Alma();
        loopProd.id=item['id']
        loopProd.id=item['data-keyword']

        detailsUrlLink=  item.find('a', attrs={'class':'item gaProductDetailsLink'})['href']
        len(detailsUrlLink)
        print detailsUrlLink
        loopProd.detailsSiteURL  = detailsUrlLink
```

and when I run, I see that the loopProd setter is getting called forever, so I yes I`m getting an **RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded** error. Please tell me, what should be the problem, and why is this code call my setter again and again until I get exception.

Please see that setter is in my custom class:

```
@detailsSiteURL.setter
def detailsSiteURL(self,v):
    self.detailsSiteURL = v
```

Comment: We appear to be missing the code that's actually required to determine the issue: where is the code for the setter - why do you just have `len(detailsUrlLink)` by itself? What was `loopProd` etc.. etc...

Comment: We need to know what `loopProd` is to know what its setter does. Do you have a custom class with a setter that calls itself repeatedly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to try and set your setter (your setter function and variable need different names):

```
@detailsSiteURL.setter
def detailsSiteURL(self,v):
    self.detailsSiteURL = v # <---- same name as function!
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For properties you normally follow this pattern (note the getter/setter methods are named `foo` and the actual variable is called `_foo`):

```
class Something(object):
  def __init__(self, foo):
      self._foo = foo
  @property
  def foo(self):
      return self._foo
  @foo.setter
  def foo(self, value):
      self._foo = value
```

Comment: okay, I had defined an _detailsSiteURL below the class definition row, and I had modified the setter to set the _detailsSiteURL variable, and now it works. Can you tell me please what is the different between self and _detailsSiteURL ? I thought I was setting an instance variable by self.detailsSiteURL

Comment: @Karoly oh you keep the `self.` you just can't have the function and the variable named the same thing :) I've updated to remove the somewhat ambiguous paragraph

Comment: loopProd.setDetailsSiteURL(detailsUrlLink);
            print loopProd.detailsSiteURL
            
and with normal funcitons, and it works :) thx,
so, I have to define the variable , before I start to use with self.  ? :D right ?

Comment: @Karoly normally it'd have a default value in the class' `__init__` - but as long as it's set before its getter is called you're okay...

Comment: jeah, it works, thanks :) 
and watch out, noob on the playground :D
thx again

Comment: @Karoly np - I've added an `__init__` to set a value so the example is more complete...